# Check String Value If Valid Date in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime, date-format

My problem is when i receive a string and that is not in date format. And put the error in textbox.

Example:

```
Public Sub get_error(ByVal sheet_name As String, ByVal column_name As String, ByVal row_count As String, ByVal row_value As String)
        Dim dt_row_service_provider_code As String = row_value
        If dt_row_service_provider_code Is Nothing Or dt_row_service_provider_code = "" Then
            dt_row_service_provider_code = "Empty Value"
        End If
        If dt_row_service_provider_code.Length > 50 Then
            dt_row_service_provider_code = "Characters is greater than 50"
        End If
        txtError.Text += "sheet: " & sheet_name & " | column: " & column_name & " | row: " & (row_count + 2) & " | row value is: '" & dt_row_service_provider_code & "'" & Environment.NewLine
    End Sub

     'dr(2).Tostring contains word "test"
     For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim holiday_code As String = dr(0).ToString
        Dim holiday_desc As String = dr(1).ToString
        Dim holiday_date As String = dr(2).ToString
       If holiday_date Is Nothing Or holiday_date = "" Then
             get_error(dt.TableName, dt.Columns(2).ToString, dt_row.ToString, "Empty Value")
        End If

          If isDate(holiday_date) = False Then
            'show error message in textbox
             get_error(dt.TableName, dt.Columns(2).ToString, dt_row.ToString, "Value is not a valid Date")
           End If
      Next
```

This is just example of mine because my program is importing excel to database and i'm just taking some scenario that if the user will accidentally add a word in date format in excel.now how can i put the error in textbox?. i don't want to just show an exception but i want to put the error in textbox

Comment: do you want to check if he accidently put a letter in the textbox?? to limit the amount of characters, you can set the maxlength.. to check if there is any letter, you can use textbox InStr function

Comment: no i mean i want to show the error in textbox and that error message is customize like i will put the row and column of the error value. 
And the value that i will receive is from excel

Answer (score 0):

Updated my answer.

```
Public Sub get_error(ByVal sheet_name As String, ByVal column_name As String, ByVal row_count As Integer, ByVal row_value As String)
   Dim dt_row_service_provider_code As String = row_value
   txtError.Text += "sheet: " & sheet_name & " | column: " & column_name & " | row: " & (row_count + 2) & " | row value is: '" & dt_row_service_provider_code & "'" & Environment.NewLine

End Sub

For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Dim holiday_code As String = dr(0).ToString
    Dim holiday_desc As String = dr(1).ToString
    Dim holiday_date As String = dr(2).ToString
    Dim newDate As DateTime
    Try
        newDate = DateTime.Parse(holiday_date)
    Catch ex As Exception
        If holiday_date = "" Or holiday_date Is Nothing Then
            get_error(dt.TableName, dt.Columns(2).ToString, dt.Rows.IndexOf(dr), "Empty Value")
        Else
            get_error(dt.TableName, dt.Columns(2).ToString, dt.Rows.IndexOf(dr), "Value is not a valid Date")
        End If
    End Try
Next
```

Comment: hmm. I'm pretty sure your code is inside a loop. Can you tell me the exception? Or much better, can you please show us the relevant parts of your code? :)